# Typescript : cannot read property 'long_name' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typeerror, angular-cli

I tried to use the  `Non-null assertion operator` as shown in [TypeScript official documentation.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) Below my code :

```
    let streetNumberComponent  = this.getAddressComponent(addressComponents, 'street_number');
    address.streetNumber = streetNumberComponent!.long_name();

    ...

    public getAddressComponent(addressComponents: Array<any>, type: string): any {

        addressComponents.filter( component => {
            let types : Array<string> = component.types;
            if(_.includes(types, type)) {
                return component;
            }
        });

        return null;
    }
```

I expected that the property `long_name()` will be accessed only if `streetNumberComponent` is not `null`. But It's not the case and I get :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'long_name' of null
```

Note that the following code works correctly :

```
address.streetNumber = streetNumberComponent && streetNumberComponent.long_name();
```

---

I'm using :

- TypeScript : **2.0.10**
- Angular : **2.3.1**
- Angular CLI : **1.0.0-beta.24**

Comment: `streetNumberComponent!.long_name();` Is that exclamation mark a typo when writing your question?

Comment: It's the TypeScript `Non-null assertion operator`.

Comment: Oh right, my bad, haven't done that much on TS haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Non-null assertion operator is only used in typescript, it does not survive the compilation process and isn't present in the js code.  As stated in the docs:

> the ! non-null assertion operator is simply removed in the emitted
>   JavaScript code

This operator doesn't really check that what's before it isn't null, it's just a way for you to tell the compiler that you're sure it isn't null, even if the compiler can't infer that itself.

Obviously when you run this code `streetNumberComponent` is null.

Comment: Thank you Nitzan. What's the real utility of such operator ? I can't see a concrete usage of it !

Comment: The example they have in the link in your question shows such a scenario. You sometimes know more than the compiler and so the language introduced different ways of correcting the compiler, one of those is this operator, another is casting/type assertion.